# customize window closing event message in IE?

Tags: gwt

i am using GWT. on window close we get browser provided message" Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?". i want to replace the message with my own message. please help me. below is my code.

```
Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onWindowClosing(final Window.ClosingEvent closingEvent) {
                                                        closingEvent.setMessage("some message.");
                    }

        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you can not modify the dialog that is opened if you provide a string in the closing event.

The dialog is handled by the browser and can not be customized.

Comment: We cannot override the default message like 'Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?'. But we can add some more information to this message by using 'setMessage' method. This is working fine in IE, but not have any effect in Fire Fox.