# Confirm Browser Exit in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, web

I want to display a confirmation dialog when users tries to leave my GWT application. If the user chooses to stay in the app, nothing is done otherwise the application should first send a logout request to the server before closing.

How can I do that?

which handler to use?

> Window.addCloseHandler

or

> Window.addWindowClosingHandler

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [methods it has](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.ClosingEvent.html), `addWindowClosingHandler` seems to be what you need.

EDIT: I think what you need to do is... `addWindowClosingHandler` is called when the window is closing, i.e. when the user clicks the close or reload button. `addCloseHandler` is called when the Window closes. So you use *both*! You use the closing handler to display a confirmation dialog, then you use the close handler to do the stuff you only want to do on close.

```
    Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new Window.ClosingHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
            event.setMessage("Do you wanna close?");
            System.out.println("Closing...");
        }
    });

    Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler<Window>() {
        @Override
        public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
            System.out.println("Closed!");
        }       
    });
```

Comment: yes but if the user chooses to stay, how to cancel the close event

Comment: Hmm, not sure about that, let me try and figure it out.

Comment: Okay I think I got it, editing my answer!

Comment: That is the correct answer. The question has also been asked and answered before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562658/execute-code-on-window-close-in-gwt

Comment: @Marconius thanks, one more thing the browser displays This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved. instead it should display my custom message

Comment: It should also be noted that you are not guaranteed to successfully fire your logout event in the CloseHandler.onClose method as the browser will shut down all of your connections. It will be a race condition where sometimes it will work and other times it will not. You might want to look into session cookies and session activity timeouts for a more complete solution to your problem.

Comment: @mmohab, you can't actually change that message, it's defined by the browser. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794264/customize-window-closing-event-message-in-ie).

Comment: You can change the message, but you can't change the dialog or style of the dialog.