# Detecting Browser Close or Tab Close without Impacting other functionality

Tags: javascript, gwt

I want to invalidate the session when the user close the tab or browser in my `GWT` Application. I saw lot of threads [Confirm Browser Exit in GWT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976998/confirm-browser-exit-in-gwt) but didn't get the solution which i am looking for. This should not fire when user refresh the browser(it shouldn't invalidate the session) and even it should not fire when user navigate to other screen or download any file.Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell the difference between closing a window or navigating away in various ways. You may be able to get around refreshing a page issue by creating a timer on the server side to see if a user requests your page again within a certain period of time, but it's not clear what benefits you get.

From a user experience view, you should offer a Sign Out (Log out) button or something similar, so a user can clearly indicate an intent to leave your app. Also, you can set an inactive timeout on your session, to invalidate session after a period of inactivity.

Comment: thanks andrei for your reply..I have implemented single sign on(Central authentication system) functionality where i have multiple application to be logged on with single credential.When the user logged out it should invalidate the session they same functionality should be applied when the user close the tab or browser.

Comment: It's easy to do - just add a closing handler to Window - but you cannot easily distinguish between different ways a user exits your app. Navigating to a different page is the same event as closing the tab.

Comment: i tried with both Window.addWindowClosingHandler & Window.addCloseHandler but its breaking other functionality like when clicking on hyperlink(for downloading files) its breaking the functionality and even its firing when i refresh the application

Comment: It should fire when you refresh the application. This is why I recommend an explicit "Sign out" button instead of invalidating session on every possible event. A user may close window by mistake and reopen it 5 seconds later - which is exactly the same as refresh. And you will force this user to login again. Set inactive timeout on your session to something low like 10 minutes if you have strict security requirements.